# Editing large binary files

Tags: c#, c++, file

I'm busy with a little project which has a lot of data like images text files and other things and I'm trying to pack it all up in one big file or multiple big files so the program folder doesn't look messy.

But the problem is how can I edit these files. I've thought about the file structure and it's going to be something like this:

```
[DWORD] Number of files

     [DWORD]FileId
     [STRING]FileName
     [DWORD]FileSize
     [DWORD]FileIndex

[BYTES]All the files
```

So the first part is too quickly get a list of all the files and the FileIndex is the Position in the binary file so I can set the pointer too for example 300 and read the file.

But if I want to create a patch and edit it I would have to read all the bytes after the file i'm editing and copy them all back which could take ages with a couple of files.

The binary file could be a few 100 mb's when all the files are inserted.

So how do other programs do this for example games use these big files and also patch a lot is there some kind of trick to insert extra bytes more quickly?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, who's going to be looking at your programs directory and caring that it looks messy? Normally people shouldn't need to care about your program's directory.

Comment: Yeah you're right about that but I'm just trying too improve my programming skills and trying out different things and right now I'm working with the file system and I could figure this one out by myself

Answer (score 3):

There is no "trick" to inserting bytes in the middle of a file.

Usually solutions involve adding files to the end of the file, then switching their position in the index.  Then you run into the problem of having to defragment the file.  You can break files into large chunks which can mitigate some of the defragmentation woes, but then the files are not contiguous.

If you are dealing with non-static data, I would not recommend doing this unless you absolutely have to.  I've seen absolutely brilliant software engineers take a considerable amount of time to write a reasonable implementation of this.

Using sqlite as a virtual file system can be a viable solution to this.  But then again, so is putting the data files in another folder so it doesn't look "messy".

Answer (score 3):

If at all possible, I'd probably package the data up into a zip file. This will not only clean up your directory, but (especially for the text files you mention) throw in some compression essentially for free. There are also, of course, quite a few existing tools and libraries for creating, examining, modifying, etc., a zip file.

Using [zlib](http://zlib.net/) (for one example), most of the work is handled for you (e.g., as demonstrated in [minizip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html)).

Answer (score 1):

You could treat the packing and editing program sort of like a custom memory allocator:

1. Use a minimum block size - When you add a file, use enough whole
   blocks to fit the file. This automatically gives the files some room
   to grow without effecting the others.
2. When a file gets too big for its current allocation, move it to the end of the package.
3. Mark the free blocks as free, and keep the offset to the head of the
   free list in the package header.  When adding other files, first
   check to see if there is a free block big enough for them.
4. When extending files past their current block, check to see if the following block is on the free list.
5. If the free list gets too long (too much fragmentation), consolodate the package.  Move each file forward to start in the first free block.  This will have to re-write the whole file, but it would happen rarely.

Alternately, instead of the simple directory you have, use something like a [FAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table).  For each file, store a list of chunks and sizes.   When you extend a file past its current allocation, add another chunk with the remainder.   Defragment occasionaly as needed.

Both of these would add a little overhead to the package, but leaving gaps is really the only alternative to rewriting the whole thing on every insert.

Comment: I would also fragment the files themselves to save space.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to make patches by overwriting the data. Otherwise, there are systems available to manage large volumes of data, for example databases.

You can create a database file that will accompany your program, and hold all your data there, and not in files. You can even embed the database code in your application, with [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/), for example, or use external DB's like Sql Server, Oracle SQL, or MySql.

What you're describing is basically implementing your own file system. Its a tricky and a very difficult task to make that effective.

Answer (score 0):

The is not way to **insert** bytes into a file other than the one you described. This is independent of the programming language. It's just how file systems work...

You can **overwrite** parts of the file, but only as long as you respect the byte count.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a .zip file?  I keep seeing formats out there where multiple files are stored as one, and the underlying file is really a zip file.  The nice thing about this is that the zip library handles the low-level bit-tracking stuff for you.

A couple examples that come to mind:

- A Word .docx file is really a zip (rename one to .zip, and you can open it -- it has whole folders in it)
- The .xap file that Silverlight packages use is another one.

Comment: Java's `.jar` files open with zip programs, but they aren't _technically_ a zip by some technicality I haven't looked into.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *managed shared memory*, supported by memory mapped file. You still have to have sufficient address space for the whole file, but you don't need to copy the whole file into memory. You can use most standard facilities with shared memory allocator, though you can quickly find that specifying custom allocator everywhere is a chore. But the good news is that you don't need to implement it all yourself, you can take **Boost.Interprocess** and it already has all necessary facilities for both unix and windows.